# How to drawan overlay with buttons, text and image on a google map

Tags: android, button, dictionary, click, overlay

I am new to android. I am working on a project which uses map. I want to draw an overlay item on a specific geopoint which contains a rectangle, some location info and a button which makes the overlay invisible when clicked. I can draw rectangle and text using drawRect() and drawText() in the draw method of overlay. The problem is that how to draw a button as a part of overlay which is clickable or something like that. Can anybody suggest something...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following links and download the code in the links

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme.

it really working nice to display button on the map.

Comment: First of all, thanks for reply. I have read those links. But that example code just adds two overlays into map. I was asking for adding buttons on map that can be clicked and some action can be performed.

Comment: Yes it is, that tutorial shows same functionality is it not? when you click the red color marker it is giving some to action...