# Showing custom pointer in google maps [Monodroid]

Tags: android, dictionary, xamarin.android

I am developing application with monodroid andI would like to insert custom pointer in my maps from Resource>Drawable.
I am able to draw text but i don't know how to insert my custom pointer in my map.
Currently it shows me small rectangle with red color in the current location of user.

Here is the code for Draw method.

```
public override void Draw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, bool shadow)
        {
            base.Draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            var paint = new Paint();
            paint.AntiAlias = true;
            paint.Color = Color.Red;

            var pt = mapView.Projection.ToPixels(_latlng, null);
            float distance = mapView.Projection.MetersToEquatorPixels(10);

            canvas.DrawText("Your Taxi is here", pt.X + distance, pt.Y + distance, paint);
           canvas.DrawRect( pt.X, pt.Y, pt.X + distance, pt.Y + distance, paint);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777022/how-to-drawan-overlay-with-buttons-text-and-image-on-a-google-map

this library works perfect for Custom map markers

Answer (score 0):

Download full working demo with custom pointer

http://www.filedropper.com/androidopenstreetmapview120516a

If map is not display in emulator or mobile device then change Map API key .

Comment: Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
      R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation);                                       Can somebody convert this code to monodroid code. i get error at getResourcee().